# Pycharm run with another version

Tags: python, pycharm

I tried to config another python interpreter for my project (2.7) but it still runs at old version (3.6).

I tried to "File >> Invalidate Caches / Restart" but it still doesn't work!

Capture https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbdCR.png

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Pycharm

Run >> Run >> Edit Configuration

On tab Configuration, please check your Python interpreter is 2.7

I pretty sure that your current interpreter was 3.6 here

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. I'm newbie and Pycharm has given to me a little bit confusing :(